# Key Bindings in LXDE (Debian)

Tags: keyboard, debian, key-bindings

I decided to use LXDE as my Desktop Environment, and I am very happy.
The only problem are the keybindings, they don't work for me.
I want to open an xterm by pressing CTRL+ALT+x, so i editet the ~/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml.
I added the following entry:

```
304     <keybind key="C-A-x">
305         <action name="xterm">
306             <command>xterm -fg green -bg black</command>
307         </action>
308     </keybind>
```

After that I typed:

```
openbox --reconfigure
```

But the Key-Binding doesn't work :(

Answer (score 2):

The action name is not just a name that you give it, but a predefined action. See the documentation for details, but to run a command you need to change the action name to 'Execute'

Answer (score 0):

There's no such action as "xterm", so you want to replace `<action name="xterm">` with `<action name="command">`. This makes it so that Openbox/LXDE knows you want to execute the command you have on the next line. Here is a full list of all actions you can use in Openbox (Openbox is the default window manager for LXDE):

http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Actions

Answer (score 0):

the openbox don't recognize the "xterm" action.
You must change it to "Execute" which will execute the command the you put just like the terminal.
I have that same trouble Good luck! :)

[code](https://gist.github.com/BruceMoustache/91e9fe041573240ac23e0e8ce24ab761)